# Import classes from external packages in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, class, package

This question has been asked more than once, but I cannot find a complete response.  I have one or more separate external packages (e.g. PkgA, PkgB, etc.) created in XCode (using File/New/Swift Package/... )   Each has various useful classes, e.g. PkgA_Class, PkgB_Class, etc. My main app (MyApp) needs to instantiate instances of the classes in those external packages. This is all fine, but how do I access the classes in PkgA and PkgB?  Documentation blithely says "they are all accessible", but that appears to be true only if the files are in the same app/package. Right now I get "Can't find PkgA_Class in scope". I did import the package into the app as a dependency.  Also tried declaring the classes 'public' but that wasn't it.  I'm sure it's something simple, but what? I know how to do this in a half-dozen languages but not Swift... TIA

Comment: If you add the package correctly all you have to do is “import” the package and then use the class. In Java for example you “import package.class” in swift you just “import package”

Comment: Having classes in package marked `public` _is_ a prerequisite. Otherwise it won't work. Once classes are marked public, in the same file where you want to use a class from package, you have to specify `import PkgA` on top of the file, and then you can use public classes from that package either without namespace (e.g. `YourClassName`), or as `PkgA.YourClassName`

Comment: The problem is that the class, Coord,  is marked public.  And I was able to add MyLibrary asa  package dependency in th main app, but when I try to import MyLibrary, XCode says it can't find it.

Comment: I have seen some info about packages having to be published :  https://daddycoding.com/2023/04/30/create-public-swift-package-manager-a-step-by-step-guide/  Is this really a requirement?

Comment: No packages don’t have to be published you can have local packages. It could be any number of things such as the package isn’t available for the platform you are compiling. Focus your search on the adding the package part make sure it shows under “Frameworks”

Comment: Oh one common issue with local packages is having the package open on 2 different Xcode windows/projects at the same time. Close all Xcode windows then reopen a window with your project. Just 1 window

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the steps you took, that leads to this issue.

Comment: (Double comment)  Restart Mac  (Apple MacBook M1 Pro, 32 GB, 2 TB, Sonoma 14.1)
Create new project (File/New), builds and shows “Hello World”
Create new Package (File/New Package in same root folder as app), accept defaults so name is “NewLibrary”
In MyLbrary Sources/MyLibrary/MyLibrary.swift create a class:
import Foundation
public class Coord {
    var x = 0
             var y = 0  }
In TestApp, I choose File/Add Package Dependencies…
Then choose “Add Local…”
 Select the “MyLibrary” folder, then the button “Add Package”
(to be continued)

Comment: This all apparently works fine. “MyLibrary” is added as a package dependency.  No errors, no warnings. Preview with “Hello World” still shown.
 In the struct ContentView in TestApp, I add   var c = Coord() which it says it can’t find in scope.  So I try importing “MyLibrary”, but it finds a lot of items to import, but not “MyLibrary”

Comment: Sorry for the messy double comment.  SO seems to have some peculiar issues with comment lengths.  But this seems like a an incredibly simple, straightforward workflow and it's hard?  I know how to to create an app and an external library in a half-dozen languages (C, C++, Java, JavaScript, etc.) but Swift?

Comment: Thanks to evryone who commented. I got it working -apparently by starting over?  :-( Whatever, the whole approach is overkill for me.